# Class of groups closed under "line supgroup"ing

Tags: gr.group-theory

Given a finitely generated group $H$, say that $G$ is a "line supgroup" of $H$ if $H < G$ (not necessarily normal), $G$ is finitely generated and for some set of generators of $G$, the Schreier coset graph of $G/H$ is either (i) finite (ii) an (infinite) line or (iii) a half-line.

The question would be: how large is the class of groups $\Gamma$ so that there is a finite chain $\{1\} = G_0 < G_1 < \ldots < G_n = \Gamma$ where $G_{i+1}$ is a "line supgroup" of $G_{i-1}$.

Clearly, you get all finite groups. Also since Polycylic admit such finite chains (with $G_{i-1}\lhd G_i$ and $G_i/G_{i-1}$ cyclic) they are also present.

**Question:** Are there groups in this class which are not finite and polycyclic groups (or extensions of such) ?

Comment: You mean: which are not virtually polycyclic groups.

Comment: @YCor actually that's what I wanted to write, but I forgot if polycyclic-by-finite-by-polyclic-by-finite... are necessarily polycyclic-by-finite

Comment: Yes (assuming you'e using the kernel-by-quotient convention): finite-by-polycyclic implies polycyclic-by-finite. So the class of polycyclic-by-finite (=virtually polycyclic) groups is closed under taking extensions.